# How are relational members from LINQ to SQL DataContext handled when objects are sent via WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, linq-to-sql

Let's say I have a relational database with tables: OrderableCategories and Orderables. They are in a relation of one-to-many with one OrderableCategory attached to multiple Orderables.     Therefore, an OrderableCategory instance in LINQ has members: `ID`, `Name` and an `EntitySet<Orderable> Orderables`. While sent via WCF (wsHttpBinding if it matters anyhow), the EntitySet is translated to simple `Orderable[]`. An `Orderable` Instance also contains a member called `OrderableCategory` which is simply an instance of this orderable's category. While sent via WCF, I guess something like this happens: an `Orderable` instance fills its `OrderableCategory` instance with fields from this category, but its `Orderable[]` is also filled with other orderables in this category. These orderables have its `OrderableCategory` filled with this category again and so on, so that I could theoretically call (for a received orderable o): `o.OrderableCategory.Orderables[0].OrderableCategory.Orderables[0]. (...)` and so on. I'm only guessing that the server gets into an infinite loop and when message size exceeds the quota, it disconnects and I see an exception of service shutting down. How can I avoid this scenario and have the benefits of relations in my database? I think my suspicions are correct, because when I disabled one of the properties (made it internal in LINQ Class Designer), the data is filled "one-way" only and the `Orderable` has no longer its `OrderableCategory` member, it works. But I would like to know if this could be achieved without compromising the property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This must be handled by marking entities with `DataContract` attribute and setting its `IsReference` property to `true`. This will instruct `DataContractSerializer` to track references instead of serialize objects as you descirbed.

Linq-To-Sql designer / SqlMetal should do this for you by setting `Serialization Mode` to `Unidirectional`.

Answer (score 0):

If you send entities over WCF, nice features like lazy loading go out the window, of course.

You basically need to decide which of the two options you'd like to use:

- if you ask for the entity `OrderableCategory`, you can return just its basic "atomic" properties, e.g. `ID, Name` and so on. The benefit is smaller size - you're sending back less data
- or alternatively: if you ask for the entity `OrderableCategory`, you can return its basic properties plus you could load a whole list of `Orderables` that this category contains, and return both at the same time; benefit: you have that data available right away, but on the downside, you'll have to send a lot more data.

Obviously, you cannot really do an infinite eager pre-loading - at some point, you have to stop and leave retrieval of more data to a later WCF service call. Your client would have to ask specifically and explicitly for yet another `OrderableCategory` if you're interested in that.